# unable to install jd-gui on ubuntu 16.04,64 bit machine

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Getting following error:

error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Already tried installing using below cmd:

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk

Getting error for this too:E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-gtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seems you need](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356605/ubuntu-64-bit-machinarium-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0) to install x86 version:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```